# Meaning of phrase "keep car in drive"

Tags: meaning

I found this phrase while listening to John Mayer's song *Why Georgia*; tried searching for its meaning to no avail.

> *I am tempted to keep the car **in drive***
>
> *And leave it all behind*

What does this mean?

Comment: [the means for making a machine or machine part move](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drive)

Comment: This is almost certainly a reference to the "D" mode in an automatic transmission car; however, note that song lyrics need not mean anything at all.

Comment: @choster fair enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]Automatic transmission reference, meaning leave it in gear, don't stop, don't park, just keep going.... "and leave it all behind".

"Put it in Drive" is an incredibly common phrase in north American English to mean "put it into gear and go". "Leave it in drive" is less common compared to a phrase such as "keep going", but for song construction you often look for a phrase with a certain number of syllables to make it work.

Comment: Do you have any source/reference?

Comment: @Rishav: this is obvious to a native speaker. It doesn't need a reference. "In drive", "in neutral", and "in reverse" are all clear and unambiguous.

Comment: I agree with @TonyK – and this question probably could have been asked on [ell.se], where it might have been less likely to garner downvotes.